# In Tauri with React, how do you properly clean up listening to events on unmount?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tauri

Say I have the following code where I am listening for the event "new_number".
When the component unmounts, I would think that it should be cleaning up the listen.

Currently I have this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe: any;

    const registerListener = async () => {
      unsubscribe = await listen<string>('new_number', (event) => {
        console.log('Received event:', event.payload);
        setNumber(event.payload);
      });
    };

    registerListener();

    return () => {
      if (unsubscribe) {
        unsubscribe();
      }
    };

  }, []);
```

This does clean up fine when React.StrictMode is turned off. But if React.StrictMode is on only one get unsubscribed.

The same things happens if I try to use a **useRef** to store the unsubscribe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally don't really trust async code in useEffect so i always stick to a Promised based approach without any issues so far, including multiple unregistering multiple listeners. In your case i would write it like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = listen<string>('new_number', (event) => {
      console.log('Received event:', event.payload);
      setNumber(event.payload);
    });

    return () => {
      unlisten.then(f => f());
    };

  }, []);
```

Comment: Thought I needed the await! Thanks a bunch, that solved it!